# Support for RTL in textfield (Arabic)

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to create a pdf file using library pdfbox. I can display a textfield with the below code but I am not able to display the cursor on the right in order the user to write from right to left. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance

```
PDTextField textField = new 
PDTextField(pdfPage.getPdDocument().getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm());
    textField.setPartialName(id);
    textField.setValue(value);

 pdfPage.getPdDocument().getDocumentCatalog().
 getAcroForm().getFields().add(textField);
 PDAnnotationWidget widget = textField.getWidgets().get(0);

 PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(x, y, width, height);
 widget.setRectangle(rect);
 widget.setPage(1);
 widget.setPrinted(true);

 pdfPage.getPage().getAnnotations().add(widget);
```

Comment: No https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4402

Comment: Do you plan to implement PDFBOX-4402 in the near future?

Comment: No current plans. This is a volunteer project. None of us speaks Arabic or is planning to learn it. What we need would be somebody who does and who has some good knowledge of the truetype font specification and who has enough free time to spend a few hours for weeks, maybe months.

Comment: How can someone contribute to the implementation of this feature?

Comment: Get the project from svn, build it, then get familiar with the codebase. Ask any questions on the users mailing list, or specific questions about the issue in the mentioned issues. The acroform stuff is done in `AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java` but I suspect it will go much deeper, i.e. `PDAbstractContentStream.showText()`, encoding, etc. I suspect that showText should be fixed first, i.e. that when Arabic is passed there that it ends up exactly that way on the PDF. This is also tricky because of the ligatures.